# Iniciar Thread com Parâmetros de Entrada para Método Void

Tags: c#, thread

Busco inicializar uma Thread que tem a função de processar uma determinada informação por um método, de modo que a linha de execução principal do programa continue rodando. Porém preciso passar dois valores para esse método. O fragmento do método que será apontado na Thread pode ser visto abaixo.

```
public class Dados
{
   public void Processamento(ulong address, string line)
   {
       string[] data = line.Split('||');
       //...
       radio.SendAndWaitForResponse(address,information);
       ...
   }
}
```

A Thread seria instanciada da seguinte forma:

```
int index = 0;
ulong addr = 0x00;
string line = "";
//...

public List<Dados> Data new List<Dados>();
public  List<Thread> Processos = new List<Thread>();
//...

Processos.Add(new Thread(Data[index].Processamento))
Processos[index].Start();
index++;
```

Isso caso meu método fosse:

```
public void Processamento() { ... }
```

Mas, gostaria que eu pudesse passar o valor das variáveis **`addr`** e **`line`** ao instanciar a Thread, como se fosse utilizar o método normalmente.

```
Processamento(addr, line);
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou clara. Afinal, qual é a sua dúvida? Você pode [edit] sua pergunta a qualquer momento para adicionar informações relevantes.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Ficou um pouco melhor, já da pra entender o que você pretende fazer. Agora me diga: o que é `Data`?

Comment: Não conseguiu da forma que eu te disse?

Comment: Deu um bug em outra parte do código , mas para esse propósito funcionou,, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se bem entendi, o que você precisa é simplesmente isso

```
var thread = new Thread(() => Data[index].Processamento(addr, line));
Processos.Add(thread));
```